# Open remote file via browser in local app and save it back to server

Tags: javascript, html, filesystems

Is it possible to open a remote file via browser in the associated local app (Word/Excel/Photoshop etc.) and have the ability to save it back to the remote server?

I tried to find some solutions, but they seem to be unavailable:

1. WebDAV - it's impossible to just generate a link for the user - the user should make a lot of things (e.g. for Windows they must create a new disk drive).
2. FileSystem API - only in Chrome (it's ok), but it cannot be accessed from a local app. Only inside the browser with filesystem:* links.

Are there any other options? Maybe it's possible to do via an extension?